# d3.js - how to delete a group element

Tags: d3.js

I want to delete a particular group element from the svg.

The code is:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 60};
var width=800, height=450;

svg = d3.select("#svgchart").append("g").attr("id","groupid").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g").attr("id", "groupid2")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(1," + (height + 1) +")")
            .call(xAxis)
            .moveToBack();

        //add the y-axis
        svg.append("g").attr("id", "groupid3")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(1, 0)")
            .call(yAxis)
            .moveToBack();

        //add an x-axis label
        svg.append("text")
            .attr("class", "x label axis")
            .attr("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("x", width)
            .attr("y", height - 6)
            .text(varxaxis);

svg.append("text")
            .attr("class", "y label axis")
            .attr("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("y", 6)
            .attr("dy", "3.75em")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .text(yaxistext);
            .....................................
            .....................................
            .....................................
```

To delete a particular group from svg:

```
svg.select("groupid").remove();
```

The group is not getting deleted.How do i remove a group?

Comment: `svg.select("#groupid").remove();`

Comment: Or rather `d3.select("#groupid").remove()` in your case as the group is equal to `svg`. Or simply `svg.remove()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A selection of `select("groupid")` will select the first *element* called "groupid".  If you want to select the first element with an ID of "groupid", you must use: `select("#groupid")`.  For classes, replace the "#" with a period.

In your case, "groupid" isn't an element.  It is an ID you have provided to a 'g' element.

So, make sure you use `select("#groupid").remove()`.  Don't forget the "#".